# Relative values over a scaled image

Tags: css, webkit

First, please consider this [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/BT4rn/1/).

I need to get some links over specific image regions, however those images are scaled according to the parent size... 
that's why the link's position and size are relative(percentages) to the image.
But the fiddle shows the problem of this approach.

Is there anyway to get the `.image-wrapper` to "mimic" the `img` size and position after scaled?! Any trick or whatever?

*Note: I'm OK with webkit-only solutions!*

#### Edit 1

Actually I'm more focused in making the image fit on the content div, then making the image wrapper follow the resulting image size. [**Here's what I achieved so far...**](http://jsfiddle.net/BT4rn/18/)
Now I'm trying to get it working with the image centralized.

Comment: Is the image's aspect ratio always going to be a portrait (height greater than width)?

Comment: @MarcAudet Sadly, no...

Comment: I worked on a related problem some time ago, and the CSS solution depended on the aspect ratio of the image.  To get around the portrait/landscape issue, I used jQuery/JavaScript to determine the image's aspect ratio and then to apply the correct CSS styling.  Would such a solution be okay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the CSS skeleton for a solution.

Suppose your HTML looks like the following:

```
<div id="content1" class="content portrait">
    <div class="panel-wrapper">
        <div class="image-wrapper">
            <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/250" />
            <a href="#" class="sample-link"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="content2" class="content landscape">
    <div class="panel-wrapper">
        <div class="image-wrapper">
            <img src="http://placekitten.com/300/200" />
            <a href="#" class="sample-link"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The HTML is similar to your original code except that there is an extra wrapper `.panel-wrapper`.

I used the following CSS:

```css
.content {
    background: lightgray;
    display: table;
    margin: 40px 0;
}
#content1 {
    width:100px;
    height:150px;
}
#content2 {
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
}
.panel-wrapper {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}
.image-wrapper {
    outline: 1px solid green;
    position:relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
.content img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
.portrait .image-wrapper {
    height: calc(100% - 2px);
}
.portrait .img {
    height: 100%;
}
.landscape .image-wrapper {
    width: calc(100% - 2px);
}
.landscape .img {
    width: 100%;
}
.sample-link {
    background:rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.3);
    position:absolute;
    display:block;
    width: 50%;
    height:20%;
    top:5%;
    left:5%;
}
```

I apply `display: table` to `.content` and `display: table-cell` to `.panel-wrapper` so that I can get a get the image centered both vertically and horizontally.

The `.image-wrapper` has `display: inline-block`.

To get the scaling right, you need to consider two cases depending on the aspect ratio of the image.

For portrait images, apply `height: 100%` to the `.image-wrapper` and the child `img`.

For landscape images, apply `width: 100%` respectively.

If you have a border on `.image-wrapper`, use the CSS `calc()` function to adjust for the 2px width of the borders.

What you need to do is use JavaScript/jQuery to determine the aspect ratio of the image and then apply the correct class (`.portrait` or `.landscape`) to the `.content` block.

See demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/SZjvJ/

Comment: Thanks! May I be able to get a css-only solution by using the `display: inline-block` trick (very neat btw).

Comment: The problem here is that CSS cannot determine the aspect ratio of the image (or any other replaced content element) in order to set either the width or the height to 100%.  You need some JavaScript help unless you can determine the aspect ratio on the server side and then server up the HTML with the correct class value (portrait or landscape).  No CSS-only solution for this type of problem, sorry!

Comment: I think your edited question still leads to the same problem and solution.  You have a block level container of specified dimensions, and you want the child image to scale either to the height if portrait or width if landscape.  The edited problem simplifies the HTML mark-up but not work around the central issue, that is, you still need to let the CSS know the aspect ratio of the image.

Answer (score 1):

A possible way is to work with image ratio and to adjust link ratio and margins according to image dimensions, with Jquery.

Have a look at this example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/t7Ucj/

The Js measures width and height of the image and according to its ratio, it works on the width or on the height of the link.

```
var width = $('#content2 img').width();
var height =  $('#content2 img').height();
//vertical image
if(height > width){
   var left = $('#content2 img').css('margin-left');
    $('#content2 .sample-link').css({'width':  width, 'left' : left});
 }
else{
  var top = $('#content2 img').css('margin-top');
   $('#content2 .sample-link').css({'height':  height*0.2, 'top' : top + height*0.4});

 }
```

Then you can wrap all the instructions in a simple function obviously.

I know it can be tricky to put all the possible cases but i had a similar problem and solved in this way.

hope it helps